# How to restrict scalling particular subview of UIScrollView while zooming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a UIScrollView which has UIImageview as its subview. That UIImageView has UIView as subview.

```
UIScrollview -(subview)-> UIImageView -(subview)-> UIView
```

When I zoom it I want only UIImageView to zoom and not UIView.

For that I scale down that UIView everytime as

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {  

      aView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1/scrollView.zoomScale, 1/scrollView.zoomScale); 
 }
```

This works fine when I only zoom in/out. At point where I start `TouchesMoved` of that aView, that view becomes scaled as per the scaling of UIImageView.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

       TempView *aView = (TempView *)[[touches anyObject] view];
        aView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1/_zoomScale, 1/_zoomScale);
    }
```

I scale down it again in `TouchesMoved` but still it shows it scalled

Comment: Did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

use `viewForZoomingInScrollView` which is a delegate method of `UIScrollView`.

If you enables pinch on `UIScrollView`, and when a pinch occurs, it calls this delegate method,there **return just imageView** which is a subView of UIView which is a subView of scrollView;